# How do I make cookies value i.e. ai_user & ai_session dynamic in JMeter as it appears different & dynamic in browser each time user hits home request?

Tags: cookies, dynamic, jmeter, session-cookies, usersession

Each time I execute home page of ecommerce website, some cookies appear in request header some of them have unique values each time we hit ***Home request*** which is **ai_user & ai_session**. I want to know how do I get those unique values in JMeter for each time I hit home request.
I recorded test script by blaze meter and it automatically recorded all cookies in HTTP CookieManager as a user defined cookies but those values are hard coded I want them dynamic as it works in browser.
I already Change the property **CookieManager.save.cookies=true** in jmeter properties file.Jmeter.properties file is located in JMeter’s bin folder and use variable **${COOKIE_ai_user}** in script to use cookie value.
But issue is its value is static I want to make it dynamic, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Each time I execute home page of ecommerce website, some cookies appear in request header

No, it doesn't work that way.

- When you open the page **first time** the browser gets cookies from [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header
- When you open the page **next time** the browser sends cookies as [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header

So the situation when you're sending cookies at the very first request is highly unlikely to happen (unless you're simulating a returning user)

It's sufficient to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter/) which simulates browser's cookie storage and automatically handles incoming cookies.

Comment: Yes its working this way
    1) When you open the page first time the browser gets cookies from Set-Cookie header
    2) When you open the page next time the browser sends cookies as Cookie header
But set-Cookies only show  "Set-Cookie: d365mkt=PK; expires=Wed, 02-Mar-2022 08:55:36 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly" in response header of 1st request, it don't show other cookies like ai_user & ai_session, how di I get those values?